# Error when connecting API Manager with Business Process Server (BPM)

Tags: wso2, api-manager, wso2-business-process, apim, wso2-esb

I'm trying to connect API Manager with Business Process Server (BPM),
**my script is** : when user trying to signup he/she must get approval from admin before registration.
**my current code** : user signup directly without permission or approval from admin and get the below error in console.
**what I did** : following this documentation https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/customizations/adding-a-user-signup-workflow/
**the error is** :
[error after signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Z0F.png)